# How to correct update realm's objects that have one-to-many relationships?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How to correct update realm's objects that have one-to-many relationships?

Imagine, i have UIViewController that somehow displays user's profile. 
It's a RLMObject that has following interface:

```
class RDBUserProfile: RLMObject {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var places = RLMArray(objectClassName: "RDBPlace")
}
```

User can edit profile. When user wants to change places i present modal UITableViewcontroller with list of its.
This UITableViewcontroller has interface like this:

```
class PlacesListViewController: UITableViewController {
    private var dataSource = [[RDBPlace]]()
    var choosenPlaces: [RDBPlace]?
    ...
}
```

I convert RLMArray to Array and pass it from initial viewController to PlacesListViewController's property "choosenPlaces" like this:

```
func placesList() -> [RDBPlace] {
  var result = [RDBPlace]()
  for object in RDBUserProfile.currentProfile().places {
    let place = objects as! RDBPlace
    result.append(place)
  }
  return result
}
```

In PlacesListViewController i somehow populate "dataSource" with array of RDBPlace (but not store in Realm).

If RDBPlace from "choosenPlaces" equals to RDBPlace from "dataSource" i mark it as "choosen".

User can dismiss mark or marks any new if wants. Then he taps "done", i close PlacesListViewController and pass to UIViewController new array of RDBPlace.

If user wants save changes he taps "save".
I update RDBUserProfile like this:

```
let userProfile = RDBUserProfile.currentProfile()
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.transactionWithBlock {
  realm.deleteObjects(RDBPlace.allObjects())
  userProfile.places.addObjects(places)
}
```

Error (crash) occurs when user chooses same set of place or adds new to existing.
I delete if from realm and try to add the same objects in same transaction.

How should correct remove all RDBPlace that are not connected to userProfile?

Comment: Recommendation. You use Objective-C Realm in your Swift code. I suggest you to use RealmSwift instead -> https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're deleting the objects you're trying to add to your `RLMArray`.

You could do something like the following to avoid the exception:

```
realm.deleteObjects(Set(RDBPlace.allObjects()).subtract(places)
```